# Dagger 2 Injecting two instances of the same object in two different fragments

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm trying to inject a pager adapter to two differentes fragments that don't exist at the same time, but each view pager has differents objects. This is what I have tried:

```
@Module
public class FragmentAModule {

    @Provides
    BaseFragment providesBaseFragment(FragmentA fragment) {
        return fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    CustomView[] providesArray(CustomView1 view1, CustomView2 view2, CustomView3 view3) {
        return new CustomView[]{view1, view2, view3};
    }

    @Provides
    PagerAdapter providePagerAdapter(CustomView[] array) {
        return new CustomPagerAdapter(array);
    }
}

@Module
public class FragmentBModule {

    @Provides
    BaseFragment providesBaseFragment(FragmentB fragment) {
        return fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    CustomView[] providesArray(CustomView4 view4, CustomView5 view5, CustomView6 view6) {
        return new CustomView[]{view4, view5, view6};
    }

    @Provides
    PagerAdapter providePagerAdapter(CustomView[] array) {
        return new CustomPagerAdapter(array);
    }
}
```

BaseFragment is a fragment that extends DaggerFragment.
CustomView is not an android.View, is a controller for each page in the PagerAdapter

Dagger error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
A binding with matching key exists in component: org.FragmentModule_ContributeFragmentB.FragmentBSubcomponent
A binding with matching key exists in component: org.MainActivityModule_ContributeFragmentA.FragmentASubcomponent
A binding with matching key exists in component: org.MainActivityModule_ContributeFragmentB.FragmentBSubcomponent
android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter is injected at
org.FragmentA.adapter
org.FragmentA is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Shijil check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

import javax.inject.Scope;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Scope
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface FragmentScope {
}

@Module
public class FragmentAModule {

    @Provides
    @FragmentScope
    BaseFragment providesBaseFragment(FragmentA fragment) {
        return fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @FragmentScope
    CustomView[] providesArray(CustomView1 view1, CustomView2 view2, CustomView3 view3) {
        return new CustomView[]{view1, view2, view3};
    }

    @Provides
    @FragmentScope
    PagerAdapter providePagerAdapter(CustomView[] array) {
        return new CustomPagerAdapter(array);
    }
}

@Module
public class FragmentBModule {

    @Provides
    @FragmentScope
    BaseFragment providesBaseFragment(FragmentB fragment) {
        return fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @FragmentScope
    CustomView[] providesArray(CustomView4 view4, CustomView5 view5, CustomView6 view6) {
        return new CustomView[]{view4, view5, view6};
    }

    @Provides
    @FragmentScope
    PagerAdapter providePagerAdapter(CustomView[] array) {
        return new CustomPagerAdapter(array);
    }
}
```

To avoid multibindings since it doesn't scale well and requires me or other workers to remember where each id go I just use an @Scope, that way those dependencies can only be called in that scope

Answer (score 0):

look you can use multibindings you can know a little more in the official documentation [Official Documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html).

additional you could try the following:

```
@Module
public class FragmentAModule {

    @Provides
    BaseFragment providesBaseFragment(FragmentA fragment) {
        return fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("array1")
    CustomView[] providesArray1(CustomView1 view1, CustomView2 view2, CustomView3 view3) {
        return new CustomView[]{view1, view2, view3};
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("array2")
    CustomView[] providesArray2(CustomView4 view4, CustomView5 view5, CustomView6 view6) {
    return new CustomView[]{view4, view5, view6};
}

    @Provides
    @Named("pagerAdapter1")
    PagerAdapter providePagerAdapter1(@Named("array1") CustomView[] array) {
        return new CustomPagerAdapter(array);
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("pagerAdapter2")
    PagerAdapter providePagerAdapter2(@Named("array2") CustomView[] array) {
        return new CustomPagerAdapter(array);
    }
}
```

and when you inject in the fragment in the activity you would do it in the following way:

```
@Inject @Named("array1") CustomView[] array1;
@Inject @Named("array2") CustomView[] array2;

@Inject @Named("pagerAdapter1") PagerAdapter pagerAdapter1;
@Inject @Named("pagerAdapter2") PagerAdapter pagerAdapter2;
```

I hope it helps you, if you do not leave a comment and I try to help you solve it.